# speeding up running if.. else loop in R

Tags: r

Does anyone know how to speed up running the following command? I want to replace the numerical "month" values with a character string ... e.g. month 1 goes to "Jul".

This command is really really slow as the dataframe I trying to implement it on is enormous!

```
for (i in 1:length(CO2$month)){
    if(CO2$month[i]=='1') {CO2$months[i]<-'Jul'} else
    if(CO2$month[i]=='2') {CO2$months[i]<-'Aug'} else
    if(CO2$month[i]=='3') {CO2$months[i]<-'Sept'} else
    if(CO2$month[i]=='4') {CO2$months[i]<-'Oct'} else
    if(CO2$month[i]=='5') {CO2$months[i]<-'Nov'} else
    if(CO2$month[i]=='6') {CO2$months[i]<-'Dec'} else
    if(CO2$month[i]=='7') {CO2$months[i]<-'Jan'} else
    if(CO2$month[i]=='8') {CO2$months[i]<-'Feb'} else
    if(CO2$month[i]=='9') {CO2$months[i]<-'Mar'} else
    if(CO2$month[i]=='10') {CO2$months[i]<-'Apr'} else
    if(CO2$month[i]=='11') {CO2$months[i]<-'May'} else
    if(CO2$month[i]=='12') {CO2$months[i]<-'Jun'}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it without a loop and without if-else:

```
set.seed(21)
CO2 <- data.frame(month=as.character(sample(1:12,24,TRUE)),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
MonthAbbRotated <- month.abb[c(7:12,1:6)]
CO2$months <- MonthAbbRotated[as.numeric(CO2$month)]
```

If your `month` column isn't really character, this is even easier:

```
set.seed(21)
CO2 <- data.frame(month=sample(1:12,24,TRUE))
MonthAbbRotated <- month.abb[c(7:12,1:6)]
CO2$months <- MonthAbbRotated[CO2$month]
```

Comment: He has a lag of 6 months here in his question: 1 corresponds to "Jul" and not "Jan". So something like `month.abb[(as.numeric(CO2$month)+6)%%12]` would correct for the lag.

Comment: just to nitpick slightly here, if you look at the OPs mapping, he has Sept, not Sep, as in month.abb

Comment: @frankc: I assumed that was a mistake. :)

Answer (score 4):

I could be missing something, but why not just use a factor?

`CO2$month <- factor(CO2$month, levels=1:12, labels=c("Jul","Aug","Sept","Oct","Nov","Dec","Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun"))`

Comment: +1 very smart, but the questioner would need to wrap that in `as.character` to get a result similar to their example.  A slightly shorter version: `factor(CO2$month, levels=c(7:12,1:6), labels=month.abb)`

Comment: That's true, but he may not actually care about the difference between a factor level and a string.  If he doesn't factor should also be more space efficient (not sure if R interns strings). If he does, then he can wrap it in as.character as you pointed out

Comment: see my comment to your answer about month.abb. Op does not *quite* use that mapping, though perhaps he meant to

Comment: Didn't mean to nitpick; just wanted to note that your answer was slightly different than theirs.  Also, characters have been stored in a hash table for the past few R versions, so they are at least as space-efficient as factors.

Answer (score 1):

```
month =c("jul","aug","sep","oct","nov","dec","jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun")

for (i in 1:length(CO2$month)){ CO2$month[i] = month[as.integer(CO2$month[i])]}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would also work, even if it's for something where there's not a neat function like `month.abb` to use:

```
Mon <- data.frame(month=1:12, months=c("Jul","Aug","Sept","Oct","Nov","Dec",
                                "Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun"))
CO2 <- merge(CO2, Mon, by="month", all.x=TRUE)
```

Comment: `month.abb` is not a function, it's just a pre-defined object.